# Angular Reactive Forms => How to trigger a validator without marking the form as invalid (warning but not blocker)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a requirement that an admin user can decide whether a validation acts only as a warning or as blocker. I still require the form to be complete (i.e. Validators.required for each control) but the pattern validator shouldn't always invalidate the form. Whether it's a warning or blocker I want an error message to show up.

Is there a way to do this with reactive forms? Or should I just hook into the onChanges and validate myself outside of the reactive forms if only warning?

```
let isOnlyWarning = true //if only warning still validate and show error but keep form valid if first validator is met (i.e. has a value)

this.form.addControl(this.textFormControlName, new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.noteSubModuleForm.RegexValidationPattern)]));
```

Comment: You can pretty easily allow the user to change the validations that are applied to the field in question to initially block the input, then allow it. What have you tried?

Comment: if in submit you don't check if (!form.valid), you can send to the server the data you want. If you want check if there're a especific error you can ask about it using hasError() or asking about the controls you need really are compliances